# How to Set a Region for a MKMapView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am new in iOS apps development and I want to put a Map in My application with a pushpin on an exact location using its latitude and longitude. I add the Map but the problem is it always appear with its initial position an the push pin doesn't appear (It is on the map but you need to change the position to see it ) . Like this figures shows :

1. Initial Position

[image: Initial Position]

2.- After I moved the map's position

[image]

What I want is to show the position of the pushpin as a default location and with a zoom .

This is a sample of My Code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate = {20.5, -7.06}; //AS an Example

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = myCoordinate;

    //Drop pin on map
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];

//Region with Zoom
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 20.5;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -7.6;


    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);


    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}
```

I used this code but still the same thing it always display the initial position (Figure 1)

Thank You .

Comment: you area using ios 7 or someother

Comment: i have paste some code below kindly edit it accordingly hope that it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  ```
  MapAnnotation *ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];



  MKCoordinateRegion region;
  region.center.latitude = 31.504679;
  region.center.longitude = 74.247429;
  region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
  region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;

  [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];




  ann.title = @"Digital Net";
  ann.subtitle = @"Office";
  ann.coordinate = region.center;

  [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
  ```

  }
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mpView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation {

  MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

  if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
      static NSString *defaultID = @"myLocation";

  ```
  pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mpView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultID];

  if(pinView == nil) {
      pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultID];

      pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
      pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
      pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

  }
  ```

  }
  return pinView;
  }

I have done something like that and it was working fine

Comment: but if you are using ios7 then i think its may be some different code